# A better way for a stacked area chart toggle between a percent scale and absolute scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-area-chart

I am a newcomer to javascript and D3.

I am trying to create a stacked area chart that toggles between showing the data on an absolute scale and a percent scale. I realize that this involves playing around with

> d3.layout.stack().offset("zero") and
>   d3.layout.stack().offset("expand").

I've succeeded in getting the chart to do what I want:

> http://jsfiddle.net/dSJ4E/

...but I'm not proud of my approach and am sure there is a better way to do it. Any ideas? Are there simple examples you might be aware of?

I am not happy with my code because upon setting up my if/else statement, I simply redeclare everything I've written prior to then, changing only the offset variable. That seems like a clunky approach. Also, I don't think this will allow me to set up transitions.

```
data = [{"type": "Group1",
             "values": [
                {"x":0, "y": 2.5},
                {"x":1, "y": 2.4},
                {"x":2, "y": 0.3}]},
            {"type": "Group2",
             "values": [
                {"x":0, "y": 1.5},
                {"x":1, "y": 1.3},
                {"x":2, "y": 1.1}]}
            ];
var stackZero = d3.layout.stack()
        .values(function(d){return d.values;})  
        .offset("zero");

stackZero(data);
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,2])
        .range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height,0])
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d3.max(d.values, function(d){return d.y0 + d.y;});})]);

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d){return xScale(d.x);})
        .y0(function(d){return yScale(d.y0);})
        .y1(function(d){return yScale(d.y0 + d.y);});       

    var svg = d3.selectAll("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +")");

    svg.selectAll(".layers")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "layer")
        .attr("d", function(d){return area(d.values);})
        .style("fill", function (d,i){return colors(i)});

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .call(yAxis);   

    d3.select("p") //now we start to interact with the chart
        .on("click", function() { 

            console.log("entering variable is " + stackType);

            svg.selectAll("path").data([]).exit().remove();
            svg.selectAll(".y.axis").data([]).exit().remove();
if(stackType){ //enter true, or expanded data

            var stackExpand = d3.layout.stack()
                .values(function(d){return d.values;})
                .offset("expand");

            stackExpand(data);

            console.log(data);

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height,0])
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d3.max(d.values, function(d){return d.y0 + d.y;});})]);

            var area = d3.svg.area()
                .x(function(d){return xScale(d.x);})
                .y0(function(d){return yScale(d.y0);})
                .y1(function(d){return yScale(d.y0 + d.y);});

            svg.selectAll(".layers")
                //.data(stackZero(data))
                .data(stackExpand(data))
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", "layer")
                .attr("d", function(d){return area(d.values);})
                .style("fill", function (d,i){return colors(i)});

            formatter = d3.format(".0%");

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient("left")
                .tickFormat(formatter);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
                .call(yAxis);


            stackType = false;
            console.log("exiting variable is " + stackType);

            } else { //enter false, or zero data

            data = [{"type": "Group1",
             "values": [
                {"x":0, "y": 2.5},
                {"x":1, "y": 2.4},
                {"x":2, "y": 0.3}]},
            {"type": "Group2",
             "values": [
                {"x":0, "y": 1.5},
                {"x":1, "y": 1.3},
                {"x":2, "y": 1.1}]}
            ];

            var stackZero = d3.layout.stack()
                .values(function(d){return d.values;})
                .offset("zero");

            stackZero(data);

            console.log(data);

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height,0])
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d3.max(d.values, function(d){return d.y0 + d.y;});})]);

            var area = d3.svg.area()
                .x(function(d){return xScale(d.x);})
                .y0(function(d){return yScale(d.y0);})
                .y1(function(d){return yScale(d.y0 + d.y);});

            svg.selectAll(".layers")
                .data(stackZero(data))
                //.data(stackExpand(data))
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", "layer")
                .attr("d", function(d){return area(d.values);})
                .style("fill", function (d,i){return colors(i)});   

            stackType = true;
            console.log("exiting variable is" + stackType);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient("left");

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
                .call(yAxis);

            };  

});
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html)? You could either use it as-is or look at the source to get some inspiration.

Comment: Yes, those capabilities are exactly what I'm interested in. Unfortunately the code seems a bit ahead of my capabilities for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a lot of things you can do to avoid repeating yourself in the code. First of all a lot of the D3 functions you are using can be reused - they are general functions. This together with the concept of javascript closures means you only have to declare them once and initialize the parts that won't change.

The stack layout does overwrite the y and y0 values, so to get the toggle to work I renamed your initial data to raw_x and raw_y and adjusted the accessors appropriately.

Then the work of figuring out the yScale domain and actually updating the paths I wrapped into a function:

```
function drawChart() {
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d3.max(d.values, function (d) {
            return d.y0 + d.y;
        });
    })]);

    // new data items need to get added
    var areas = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.type; });

    areas.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "layer")
        .style("fill", function (d, i) {
            return colors(i)
    });

    // Added and updated items need to be updated
    areas.attr("d", function (d) {
        return area(d.values);
    })

    // Old items need to be removed - we should not actually need this with the data as it is
    areas.exit().remove();

    svg.selectAll("g.y.axis").call(yAxis);
}
```

It's really just a start and you will want to reorganize based on your needs, but take a look at an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/dSJ4E/1/)

Comment: I noticed that I can shorten `var areas = svg.selectAll(".layer").data(data, function(d) { return d.type; });` by removing `function(d) { return d.type; }` and it still works. Is there a reason that you included that bit?

Comment: Does this mean that in future applications I should avoid using the tags "x" and "y" for my data? After all, since "x" and "y" are already being used by svg.stack.layout (you mentioned that stack overwrites values), then having data that includes those labels would seem to add unnecessary confusion.

Comment: A lot of the layouts will set x and y attributes so I often like to keep my raw data separate and use accessors. Especially as often you need the raw data for several pieces - like labels or tooltips. The pixel location values are rarely meaningful. It also means you do not have to keep track of what your current x or y values are showing when switching layouts - as you discovered.

Comment: This question is pretty old now, so you have probably discovered that the ``function(d) { return d.type; }`` bit is a key function to allow D3 to associate each piece of data with a unique key in order to provide object constancy.  This allows D3 to animate your data in more meaningful ways.  See here for details: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/